# Setting a specific width in flex boxes

Tags: css, web, layout, flexbox

There is a flex container. How can I set specific widths of specific elements in it (either in% or in px)? (examples are desirable)

Comment: The same way as normal. Just set a width.

Comment: You can use `flex` or `width` to set it

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout this

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

span {
  flex:1;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.item {
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <span>1</span>
  <span class='item'>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
</div>
```